# Global search- I want search results to be displayed all related records of account and also records of their account hierarchy

Tags: global-search

I have an account with account hierarchy setup and there is one Custom object "Agreement" added as related list on the account. When, I search an account with an account name on global search **I want all related agreement records of that account as well as of all account comes under the account hierarchy**, to be displayed after search. How to achieve this in Salesforce?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (Please see [ask] and [edit], don't comment).

Comment: I want solution, how to do it? I need to write any code for this to achieve?